# Java ScriptEngine Share Global Scope

Tags: java, scripting, jython

I've started using ScriptEngine to write Jython code, and figured a neat way to debug might be running the Jython code:

```
import code
code.interact(local=globals())
```

I want to share the outer Java environment with the ScriptEngine environment, so for example I could call other object methods in a class or if I had variables defined previously (such as function arguments) I could use them. I know I can explicitly load these with `engine.put()` and `setBindings()` but I'd like to have this done mostly automatically. Is there something similar to Python's `globals()` (or `locals()`) function in Java that would get me a Context of the current code? Maybe something with introspection...